# How do I remove older versions of gpg on Raspbian OS?

Tags: gpg

I am trying to install the latest version of GnuPG library on a Raspberry Pi 4 device. I find that the Raspbian OS already comes with installed gpg binaries, which is not allowing me to install newer versions of required libraries (ex. libgcrypt). I checked /usr/bin after carrying out all installation steps, only to find older versions of gpg files.

Previously, I was able to successfully install and run gpg2 library commands on an Ubuntu VM. How can I do the same in the Pi 4 device, considering Raspbian is also Linux based OS?

Answer (score 0):

first try `sudo apt install gnupg --reinstall`
this should overwrite.

if above is not what you need, try running

`sudo apt --purge remove gnupg`

also, including `-f` in most apt commands will force the action.

Comment: the top one should be enough. Your type of situation is what the --reinstall flag's entire reason for existence...   It tels dpkg that target pkg is already installed, but needs overwritten.

Comment: I tried now both the commands. But they don't seem to work. The old binaries remain intact.

Comment: While executing 'purge' command, it removed 'apt' package as well (this occurs even after removing '--purge' option, and including '--autoremove' option). I had to reinstall Raspbian OS to recover 'apt' package.  On this fresh installation, I find the latest supported 'gpg' version to be 2.2.12 as compared to 2.3.1. Libgcrypt versions differ as well (1.8.4 for Raspbian vs 1.9.3 for Ubuntu). I will proceed with this older GnuPG package for my work as of now.

Comment: I have no idea why this would happen... As long as gnupg was installed when you issued the command, it should have removed that package only. The --purge flag tells it to remove associated config files. Either this command works differently on Raspbian (which still doesnt explain apt package being deleted) or else it is some sort of bug. What did the log files have to say on the matter?

Comment: Also, if you ever lose apt again, you can use dpkg to get it back. Search for and download the libapt-pkg .deb file and use sudo dpkg -i <.deb file>    also, while i was searching for a suitable download, i saw this gnupg file which might help...  https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/apt

Comment: It looks like installing GnuPG and its dependent packages from its tarball on Raspbian is the culprit. Maybe I am missing some key step during installation. But the 'apt' package does get removed on trying to execute --purge command. Even if I install 'apt' using dpkg command, I am still not able to recover back the pre-installed GnuPG package upon trying to install new version via tarball. Pasting the relevant error for 'apt' below for clarity:

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads/tmp $ sudo apt-get --purge remove gnupg
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  python-apt-common python3-apt python3-debconf
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apt* apt-listchanges* apt-utils* gnupg* raspbian-archive-keyring* tasksel*
  tasksel-data*
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  apt raspbian-archive-keyring (due to apt)

Comment: It is not letting me format the command log. Please bear with this unformatted output.

Comment: Are you trying to install directly from a tarball (i.e. using the command line?) If so, your problem is probably the tarball itself... Since the job of the purge flag is removing dependencies (although, as far as I know, this is meant to be limited to file dependencies such as configuration files, and not packages) and according to the notification you're getting, APT is being deleted as an unneeded dependency, I'd say that GnuPG is okay, but the configuration is wrong. Where are you getting the tarball from?

Comment: Also, remember that running update & upgrade automatically finds and installs the newest version of every app in the apt repos (every app that works with `apt install`) The only exception is when upgrade will cause apt to change the install status of (install or uninstall) another package. In other words, if the dependencies change... Which brings us back to the tarball having the wrong dependencies, no?

Comment: I was downloading it directly from their website: https://www.gnupg.org/download/index.html. I had tried the 'apt update/upgrade' option before on Raspbian and the result showed that the latest version was installed already. I concluded that latest version for Raspbian might be different from latest version for Ubuntu. The whole purpose behind this version stuff was to maintain uniformity across target platforms for my work. I am unblocked now (will note the differences in version while recording results).

Comment: if apt is the default pkg mgr for raspbian, then I would use its repositories for your versioning benchmarks. Im sure youve heard the saying "The pkg mgr is one of the most powerful tools available to a Linux user." One of the main reasons for this is because the management is more or less automatic. With just two quick commands(update and upgrade), parity is achieved. Update finds the newest version for your system (remember it is also tracking all dependencies -- what works together and what doesn't), and upgrade installs them. This way your guaranteed to have the newest versions that wrk 4u

Comment: Ran out of room at the end : ) hopefully that didnt sound condescending. my point was that you can usually rely on your pkg mgr. as you know, the keyword is "usually."

Comment: Thanks for the useful tip. I will keep that in mind for future installations/upgrades.

Comment: I had an idea this morning for a way to find out exactly what is changing in these situations. When something unexpected happens on your machine, and you're able to get it back to an acceptable state, but you need to know what is happening and why in order to move forward, you can use git in order to find out. If you init a git repo directly inside the /   and commit, you can then reproduce the problem "i.e.       
--purge remove, and then make a second commit.

Comment: Now all you need to do is type git diff, and you'll magically see a list of every character in every file in every folder on your system that changed as a result!!!

Comment: The best environment for this would probably be a VM sandbox with an image of your machine. That's a little extra work, but sometimes it's worth it. I plan to get on Reddit in a little while and see if anyone else on there has ever tried this. Just curious to see how common it is.

Comment: That's a superb idea! I have not tried creating a VM sandbox using Raspbian image. If time permits, I will try that out and report my findings.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to location of shared library file libgcrypt*.so and updating path of executable to newly generated gpg binary.